# Do all disbelievers go to Hell eternally including Muslims with low faith?

Tags: practical-islam, jahannam

I’m a born Muslim. I became agnostic for a few years but I’ve went back to being a Muslim again, alhamdulillah.

My family are also Muslim except my one of brothers became an agnostic and the other an atheist.

They are still good people and I really care about them but I worry that they will go to hell forever especially when I read verses in the Quran or hadiths that say that.

I’m also not a good Muslim myself. I feel like a disbeliever at times or a hypocrite. I told everyone that I’m Muslim but sometimes I question a lot of stuff about Islam (not saying there’s anything wrong with Islam, it’s perfect, its just me that has a hard time believing).

**My question is would all disbelievers stay in hell eternally? What about Muslims like me who have low faith or feel like a disbeliever at times?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who stays in Hell forever per Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42803/who-stays-in-hell-forever-per-islam)

Answer (score 0):

Will all disbelievers stay in hell eternally?

The simple answer is, Yes, even if they were good in this world, their good deeds are wiped away, All of it! Even If they did jihad for the sake of Allah but were still kafirs, even if they did Hajj and it was accepted and they did it for the sake of Allah but they were still kafirs and died on kufr/shirk, making it guaranteed hellfire for a kafir since they have no good deeds, and since if a person died on shirk, they are bound to be in hellfire forever.
**Evidence:**

Surah Zumar

Surah Furqan

What about muslims who feel like they have weak Iman or think they are kafirs?

It is better to take heed of their feelings by increasing Iman,

For muslims who sometimes think they are kafirs, it is even better for them to take heed of this by repenting from every sin they committed for the sake of Allah. (I'd recommend you to research about the conditions of tawbah and do tawbah, since it is an order from our prophet (peace be upon him) to do tawbah and it is sunnah to do it a 100 times a day)

**Evidence:**

Sahih Muslim 2702

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Please provide sources

Answer (score -3):

Well, as long as they have converted to Muslim with the Islamic creed "There is no God besides Allah and Muhammad is His Messenger" (Aka "لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله). Or else their good deeds may not be accepted. If they are People of the Books , and if they believe in only ONE God (NOT Christians as they have Trinity) , their sins MAY be forgiven, we do not know, but Allah knows best.
Salam

Comment: You are telling me, a laymen who has memorized the Quran will take his/her relative out of hellfire to Paradise when even the Prophet() himself can't do it?

Comment: Intercession does not apply to disbelievers. See https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/51296/20218

Comment: @UmH - Mashallah brother, you are very knowledgeable. Is there any way I can directly contact you? I run a Muslim Apologetic Group on Facebook and we are in search for knowledgeable Muslim brothers like you. We will be glad to have you in our group.

Comment: @User10668 bye then?